# iOS 11 expanding navbar stops expanding after scroll up

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios11

I have implemented two different tableviews. The first uses a `UIViewController` and a `UITableView`. The second uses a `UITableViewController` with static cells.

I currently have `prefersLargeTitles = true`. On the first view controller, the navbar expands as I drag down the table as expected. However, after I scroll up making the navbar shrink, letting go and pulling down on the table again does not expand the navbar and it seems to be "stuck" after that.

This is not an issue on the second controller that uses a `UITableViewController`.

This issue does not occur on the simulator, but has occurred on two different iPhone 7's (iOS 11.2 beta 4, iOS 11.1.2)

As you can see below, after I go to scroll back down after scrolling up, there is a slight jolt then it sticks. The navbar no longer expands after this point (it does collapse still).

[image: Scrolling Stick]

Here is an example of what should occur and happens with the `UITableViewController`.

[image: Scrolling Success]

Is this an iOS 11 issue?

Comment: Try setting the table view's `alwaysBounceVertical` to `true`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have that set to `true` and still no luck

Comment: Oh well... It really might be a system issue; I suggest packaging up a demo and sending it off in a bug report to Apple. They've never been good at "loose" table views and scroll views; they always seem to assume you're using a table view controller and the table view occupies the screen.